# Create a "differences" data frame

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm trying to build a program to generate "differences reports" for users in my business group.

So I have constructed data frames out of prior version and current version of files we receive. The df's look like

Prior File:

| Item Code | Price |
| --- | --- |
| AAA | 12.9 |
| BBB | 8 |
| DDD | 3.2 |

New file:

| Item Code | Price |
| --- | --- |
| AAA | 14.5 |
| BBB | 8 |
| CCC | 5 |
| DDD | 3.2 |

I want to compare these 2 DF and output a new DF that looks like this:

| Old Item Code | New Item Code | Item Code Diff | Old Price | New Price | Price Diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | AAA | FALSE | 12.9 | 14.5 | TRUE |
| BBB | BBB | FALSE | 8 | 8 | FALSE |
|  | CCC | TRUE |  | 5 | TRUE |
| DDD | DDD | FALSE | 3.2 | 3.2 | FALSE |

So I am showing item code CCC is new, Item Code AAA had a price change and item codes BBB + DDD are unchanged.

Currently I have DFs that match prior_file and new_file and am comparing them like this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_old_file = pd.read_excel(old_excel_file)
df_new_file = pd.read_excel(new_excel_file)

diff_cols = df_new_file.columns.values

for i in diff cols:
    df_new_file[i, 'diff'] = np.where(df_new_file[i] == df_old_file[i], 'True', 'False')

print(df_new_file.head())
```

I don't think this is working correctly, as any new code like CCC will cause every subsequent record to show as a diff.

Thank you!

Edit: I am now using a df.join and getting closer

```
df_results = df_old_file.join(df_new_file.set_index(item code), how = 'outer', on='item code', lsuffix='_old', rsuffix='_new')

print(df_results.head())
```

gives

| Item Code | Price_old | Price_New |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 12.9 | 14.5 |

Now I just need to create the difference 'true', 'false' columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I wanted to share the answer I came up with today:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
#read the files into DFs
df_old_file = pd.read_excel(old_excel_file)
df_new_file = pd.read_excel(new_excel_file)
#Merge DFs
df_results = pd.merge(df_old_file, df_new_file, 
how="outer", left_on="ITEM CODE", right_on="ITEM CODE", suffixes=('_old','_new')

#list of cols
diff_cols = df_new_file.columns.values
#remove key from comparison
diff_cols.remove('ITEM CODE')

#find if diff and create diff indicator column
for i in diff_cols:
    df_results[i,'diff'] = np.where(df_results[i+'_old'] ==
    np.where(df_results[i+'_new'], '', 'diff')

print(df_results)
```

This gives

| ITEM CODE | PRICE_OLD | PRICE_NEW | ('PRICE', 'diff') |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aa | 12.9 | 14.5 | diff |
| bb | 8 | 8 |  |

It's also extensible to a worksheet with any N number of columns.

Comment: nice to see you took time to do research on your problem. Using integrated functions is usually prefered in python so your answer is even better than my "hand made" solution

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using this kind of architecture to store the data and compare it

```py
class singleData():
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value

class datas():
    def __init__(self):
        self.listOfData = []

    def add(self, newData): # take a data object
        self.listOfData.Append(newData)

    def nameExist(self, name):
        for data in listOfData:
            if data.name == name:
                return True
        return False

    def getValue(self, name):
        for data in listOfData:
            if data.name == name:
                return data.value
        return;
```

using it like this:

```py
myDatas = datas()

# here I manually add elements but do it using panda
myDatas.add(singleData("AAA", 12.9))

#when comparing with new elements, just do a nameExist check and then get value using getValue
AAAExist = myDatas.nameExist("AAA")
if AAAExist:
    AAAOldValue = myDatas.getValue("AAA")
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I spent more time today learning pd.merge and I think I came up with a solution. Posted it as an answer to my own question, please take a look and let me know what you think!